# How to get token after creating user account on ebay?

Tags: oauth, token, sandbox, ebay-api

Do we get token on creating seller account on eBay or we have to generate it manually through developer login.I'm really stuck with this problem.Please help if anyone knows!!

Answer (score 0):

The relevant documentation is [here](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-client-credentials-grant.html) but I'll sum it up:

You need an eBay user account. (The term "seller account" means "user account that happens to sell things", which is useful for people who have two accounts and only sell with one of them.)

You also need a developer account.

Using your developer account, you write a program that prompts a user to sign in and request an access token with permissions you specify.

This prompts eBay to send a token to your program, which expires in 2 hours. Just enough time for your program to do all the eBay tasks it needs to do.

If 2 hours isn't long enough, there is a way of using the first token to create more tokens, but you still need the user to sign in once every 18 months to keep your program running.

There is no way to gain indefinite access. Sorry.